# Sensa Touch 1.1 with JSONP Object calls only the first time

Tags: caching, sencha-touch, jsonp

I am trying to get an answer from a server through an Ext.util.JSONP.request. The code works fine and calls the callback function, but only for the first time. I have searched a lot about it, but the solutions I saw do not provide a solution for me. My Code is:

```js
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    method: 'GET',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    callback: function(data){
        alert('data');
    },
    url: myUrl,
});
```

I tried adding changing params for every call in callbackparams as well as at the end of the url with `?param=myParam`, being myParam different in every call.

I tried adding `disableCaching: true`

I tried to add to the response:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```

I also tried calling the url directly from the browser and this works fine, every time I call I receive a new answer, thus it is not a problem from the server.

I do not know what else could I test. Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.